# Java How to write variable into H2 database

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, h2

I am trying to write variable into H2 database but it keep giving me error. The part below work.

```
 pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cart (Number, Item, Quantity, Value) " 
         +"VALUES ('1','Book','5','10')");
 pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

After I change the Values into variable, it dont work anymore. I have tested it with SQL it work but not in H2 database. Anyone know how can I get this to work?

```
 String Number = "2";
 String Item = "Fruit";
 String Quantity = "10";
 String Value = "2";

pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cart (Number, Item, Quantity, Value) " 
         +"VALUES ("+Number+","+Item+","+Quantity+","Value+")");
 pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:(single quote is needed if the database field type is string)

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cart (Number, Item, Quantity, Value) " 
     +"VALUES ('"+Number+"','"+Item+"','"+Quantity+"','"Value+"')");
```

I will suggest you to use `parameterised queries` to avoid `SQL Injection`

Using `Parameterised statements`:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cart (Number, Item, Quantity, Value) " 
     +"VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1,Number);
pstmt.setString(2,Item);
pstmt.setString(3,Quantity);
pstmt.setString(4,Value);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: @user2822351  Yes, the second method which I have described is using `Parameterized Query` in which we use `?` as a placeholder for values, and use `setXXX()` methods to set value. You can read more about `Parameterized Query` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is that the string you are creating will have no single quotes. (Bhushan in a different answer shows one way to get the quotes in there.)

The extended answer would be "Please don't ever construct SQL queries this way.  Use query parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks."